# Чем заменить ".decode("unicode-escape")" в Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, utf-8, unicode

Есть строка, которая содежит в себе много юникода, вот отрывок:

\u0426\u0435\u043d\u0442\u0440

В Python 2, можно было дописать .decode("unicode-escape") и все работало, но в Python 3. Пишет ошибку AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'

Как в Python 3 декодировать в UTF-8?

Comment: `print("\u0426\u0435\u043d\u0442\u0440")` выводит `Центр`

Comment: «декодируют» не в utf-8, а в строку. У строк в питоне нет явно определённой кодировки с точки зрения программиста

Comment: `import codecs; codecs.decode(r'\u0426\u0435\u043d\u0442\u0440', 'unicode-escape')`

Comment: @andreymal, Большое спасибо, работает.

Comment: Всем спасибо за разъяснения

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
print("\u0426\u0435\u043d\u0442\u0440".encode("UTF-8").decode("UTF-8"))
```